# Why dropdown selecting last value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

Here i try to Loading data into dropdownList Its Loading But why By default it select last value from the List.

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="Part5Controller">
    Country : <select ng-model="CountryID" ng-options="I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountryList" ng-change="GetState()">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**controller.Js**

```
app.controller('Part5Controller', function ($scope, servicemard) {
    getCountrys();
    function getCountrys() {
        var xx = servicemard.getctrys();
        xx.then(function (d) {
            $scope.CountryList = d.data;
        })
    }
})
```

**service.js**

```
app.service('servicemard', function ($http) {
    this.getctrys = function () {
        return $http.get('/Jan/GetCountries')

      }
})
```

Comment: Can you add the 'Jan/GetCountries' response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to kill two birds with one stone. Giving the "prompt" option a value makes you then have to deal with it. Probably the better way is to pre select and disable it.

```
<div ng-controller="Part5Controller">
    Country : <select ng-model="CountryID" ng-options="I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountryList" ng-change="GetState()">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Country</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now, the prompt is selected by default but cannot be actually selected for the binding. My experience is with a null value on the binding without a selection results in the last item in the list being selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's `ng-model` keeps in sync value of the target property and state of the widget. In your case it means that option with `CountryID` equal to your controller's scope `CountryID` is selected. I do not see any definition of controller's `CountryID`, so I think you should try to be explicit.

Set up your empty option as

```
<option value="-1">Select Country</option>
```

And add `CountryID` initialization in controller

```
$scope.CountryID = -1;
```